# Unmarshal Group with Nested XML-RPC in Go

Tags: xml, go, xml-rpc, unmarshalling

I'm using Webfaction API and trying to unmarshal their response to obtain the session ID (12345abcde... below).

How do I access the specific value when its nested under several fields (namely, params>param)?

Code below is at http://play.golang.org/p/krG4_fXVka

```
package main

import ("encoding/xml"
        "fmt"
        )

type Result struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"methodResponse"`
        Values []string `xml:"params>param>value"`
}

func main() {
data := `
    <methodResponse>
<params>
    <param>
        <value><array><data>
            <value><string>12345abcde12345abcde12345</string></value>
            <value><struct>
                <member>
                    <name>username</name>
                    <value><string>trex</string></value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>home</name>
                    <value><string>/home</string></value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>mail_server</name>
                    <value><string>Mailbox1</string></value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>web_server</name>
                    <value><string>Web12</string></value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>id</name>
                    <value><int>1234</int></value>
                </member>
            </struct></value>
        </data></array></value>
    </param>
</params>
```

`

```
v := Result{}
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
if err != nil {
fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
}
fmt.Printf("XMLName: %#v\n", v.XMLName)
fmt.Printf("Values: %#v\n", v.Values)

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but this seems to break it down better?

```
type Member struct {
    Name string `xml:"name"`
    Value string `xml:"value>string"`
}

type Result struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"methodResponse"`
        FirstValue string `xml:"params>param>value>array>data>value>string"`
        Members []Member `xml:"params>param>value>array>data>value>struct>member"`
}
```

Note that the structure your parsing has a fairly insane level of depth. Might help to run the XML through a pretty printer that formats it for you with indent to see.

Comment: Does a method exist to post-process and eliminates redundant depth?  Agree that the insane depth throws me off

Comment: Not sure you need to postprocess it - after you run it through that, you just get a straight string ie: v.FirstValue == "12345abcde12345abcde12345". You have to spec where you want it to fish the data from somewhere ... might as well be in the xml tag.